# Adding members to on premises VSTS web page just loads forever

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using an on premises VSTS server. I'm the owner.

My problem is very simple. I have created a project and set up Git version control on that project. It works beautifully. However, when I go to Add users on the main project page, a loading spinner appears that just loads forever (like, say, 10 minutes). Equally, if I go to the users tab, which would be another way to add them, I believe, it just infinitely loads again.

Tried Chrome and IE9. Tried logging in and out. Tried on multiple days, multiple times. I really can't think of anything else to try. I can't find anyone on the internet with the same problem.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Do you want ass users to team project? team member? git repository permissions? can you share the screen?

Comment: @Chris Beeley, Like  Shayki Abramczyk's suggestion, it would be better if you could share a screen shot about where you add the members, for example, if you add users to this new project, how about just adding only one user? Whether it has been assigned an access level in your VSTS? Maybe you could test it in other machine using latest browser like IE11 or others, if you get any latest information, please share it here.

Comment: Sorry, the problem magically went away. Which is weird because it lasted for a week. I've voted to close

Comment: @Chris Beeley, Glad to know that it has been resolved. Maybe it is the Server issue or the network loaded issue.